# Xdebug profiling accuracy regarding function calls

Tags: php, profiling, xdebug

I do not know how to properly describe or c/p an Xdebug output, so I rely on the screenshot here. Given is a function which is clocked at 64.66% "incl" and 60.61% "self" costs (as of the total run-time of the software), so I had a closer look at it.

The 60.61% are shown in line 780 which corresponds to the function header and does... what exactly? Receiving two scalar parameters and returning the reference to an object - how can this be 90% of total costs when the body calls a couple of methods, some of them with every function call, others really expensive, e.g. with database access in line 805?

(And there are other methods called twice as often but contributing only with <1% to the total score)

Is Xdebug correct here, and if so, what does it tell me? There is quite a lot of documentation on usage, but not much on how to interpret the results in detail.

[image: screenshot of Xdebug output]

Comment: Any tool that says it's "powerful" makes me suspicious, and any profiler showing "self time" is likely to be blind to I/O. So your program could be spending 99% of it's time in database querying (for example). That means even if you could reduce all the self-time to **zero** by clever coding, you would only get a 1% speedup. To see what it's actually doing, you need to interrupt it at random.

Comment: Up to now I have seen significant "self"-values almost only with PHP-commands (especially the pg_* instructions for Postgres access) and loop-structures, so I felt quite comfortable. But here, with so much time spent in a function header I am puzzled - was hoping there is an (ideally helpful) explanation, but perhaps you're right.